# Using textbox to add to link

Tags: html

With my pretty limited programming knowledge, I'm throwing up a site for my university to make alum listservs.  I would like moderators to be able to enter their list name in a text box, hit enter, and have it take them to the login page for mailman.

All the login pages look like "http://host292.hostmonster.com/mailman/admin/LISTNAME_wahoowa.net/"

Is there any way to get the "LISTNAME" to be sub-ed with the text (their listname) they enter?

Cheers

Comment: Not without JavaScript or server side processing.

Answer (score 0):

As Felix says, not without JavaScript or server-side processing, but a very quick and dirty solution (so as to avoid missing my train) using JavaScript would be...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function goToLogin() {
   var name = document.getElementById("listname");
   document.location.href = 
  "http://host292.hostmonster.com/mailman/admin/" + name + "_wahoowa.net/";
}
</script>

<input id="listname" type="text"/>
<button onclick="goToLogin()">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with jQuery.

```
<input id="login">
<button id="go">Go!</button>

$('#go').click(function(){
    var login = $('#login').val();
    var sendTo = "http://host292.hostmonster.com/mailman/admin/" + login + "_wahoowa.net/"; 
    document.location.href = sendTo;   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/7cvgG/1/